# DateTime.TryParse seems to be losing the original timezone information and converting to server time

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, timezone

I have an ASP.Net form with a date/time control on it. If the form is posted back due to validation errors, the date/time is converted to the servers timezone and set as the value in the date/time control - causing the original timezone information to be lost.

I am using `DateTime.TryParse` which parses the date into the server time and seems to be losing the original timezone. I want to check if the page is a PostBack and skip the server timezone conversion if at all possible - so I keep the original value.

I tried using `TryParseExact` which has the timezone information however I couldn't work out what format I should be sending in.

```
string hiddenDateTime = "2019-09-01T18:28:00.000+0800";
DateTime dateValue;
DateTime.TryParse(hiddenDateTime, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                  DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue);
```

Is there a way to stop this conversion to local from happening and keeping the original timezone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, this is how [DateTime.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) method works;

> If s contains no time zone information, result contains a DateTime
>   value whose Kind property is DateTimeKind.Unspecified when the method
>   returns. **If the string to be parsed contains time zone information,
>   result contains a DateTime value whose Kind property is
>   DateTimeKind.Local when the method returns.**

`DateTime` object itself neither keep timezone information nor keep [UTC Offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) value. When you use some parsing operations on a string, it is usually normal to lost these values.

It is not clear what value you try to get exactly but I suggest a few things to get;

1. If you use [`DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimestyles?view=netframework-4.8) instead of `DateTimeStyles.None`, you will get a DateTime as `9/1/2019 10:28:00 AM` which has `Utc` as a `Kind` property since this enum value is exactly what this for.
2. Other than this, since your string has a UTC Offset value, I would parse it to [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netframework-4.8) instead of `DateTime`. With parsing to `DateTimeOffset`, you can keep both of them on it's [`Offset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.offset?view=netframework-4.8) and [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.datetime?view=netframework-4.8) properties.

Comment: DateTimeOffset does what I wanted - Thanks!